# how to hide svg element after animation

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to hide the images in my SVG when the animation is finished. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I have thus far:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g> 
    <image id="image1" x="65" y="155">
        /*Step1.Animation*/
        <animate id="startid" dur="1.5s" attributeName="y" values="155; 135;" begin="indefinite" />
    </image>
    <image id="image2" x="75" y="5">
        /*Step2.Animation*/
        <animate id="move" dur="1.5s" attributeName="y" values="5; 20;" begin="startid.begin" />
        /*Step3. Doesn`t working !!!*/
        <animate dur="0.1s" attributeName="visibility" from="visible" to="hidden" begin="move.end" repeatCount="0" />
    </image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2xn4y1gn/)

Comment: You want someone to code that up for you? Or have you tried something that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this statement:

```
    <animate dur="1" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="move.end" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
```

Your Example edited http://jsfiddle.net/whbjw6g2/

```
   <svg version="1.1" width="184" height="228" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 185 230">
<rect x="0" y="0" style="fill:rgb(30,176,233)" width="184" height="228" ></rect>
<g> 
    <image id="image1" x="65" y="155" width="30" height="50"  xlink:href="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/cursor.png">
        /*Step1.Animation*/
        <animate id="startid" dur="1.5s" attributeName="y" values="155; 135;" begin="indefinite" />
    </image>
    <image id="image2" x="75" y="5" width="30" height="50"  xlink:href="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/cursor.png">
        /*Step2.Animation*/
        <animate id="move" dur="1.5s" attributeName="y" values="5; 20;" begin="startid.begin" />
        /*Step3. Doesn`t working !!!*/
        <animate dur=".1" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="move.end" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
    </image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That`s it! Thank you very match

Answer (score 1):

You just need to animate the opacity from 1 to 0 like so:

```
<animate dur="0.2s" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="move.end" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
```

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. Fill='freeze' - is my problem!

Comment: Oops, Yeah I completely forgot that. Thanks